# Django sync one-to-one models

Tags: python, django

I simplify my code structure, which contains two models:

```
# created by third part app, not Django one
# but we share same DB, so i have access to this one
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        manage = False


class B(models.Model):
    model_a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='+')
    # other fields, to extend model A functionality
```

Is this a good way to extend third part app model A with my additional fields and methods? Now i have problem to sync this models true one-to-one field. Since I don't have access to trigger model A creation.

In ideal world i should have CarA and CarB. And CarB = CarA relation should be created if CarB exists.

I base this idea on Django 1.5 user extension. Is this clear enough? Or should i do something else?

Comment: why don't you add the extra fields in model A with (blank=True, null=True) and only fill them if you want?

Comment: @yanik, are you saying `class A` is a third party's model? If so, you can still register signals on it.

Comment: @Brandon "# created by third part app, **not Django one**"

Comment: Ah. Still waiting for coffee to kick in :)

Comment: @Brandon, i don't want touch this DB table because it's from other package, and i almost sure this will bite me in the ass laster :) But if I don't find better ideas - this will be the only way to go

Comment: can i use inheritance ?

Comment: @yanik how would inheritance solve your problem ?

Comment: for example i have instance `model_a`, so i can make query with ORM:
`B.objects.all()`, and it will return `['Model A Instance __str__`]. Am I right?

Comment: Yup, just done some tests. You **can't use** inheritance in this case.

Comment: With inheritance, `B.objects.all()` will only return existing `B`  instances, `A` instances with no related `B` will be ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a property to create the B instance on access if it doesn't exist yet, ie,

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    # other fields ...

    class Meta:
        manage = False


    @property
    def b(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "__bcache"):
            self.__bcache, created = B.objects.get_or_create(model_a = self)
        return self.__bcache
```

It seems like you're new to both Python and Django so let's explain quickly...

First, the "@property" part: it's a [decorator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) that turns the following function into a computed attribute - IOW you use it as an attribute (`myA.b.whatever`), and under the hood it turns it into a method call (`myA.b().whatever`). It's not strictly required here, we would have used an explicit getter (the same method named `get_a()`) but it's cleaner that way.

Then our method implementation: obviously we don't want to hit the database each time someone looks up `A.b`, so

- first we check if an attribute named `__bcache` ("b" "cache") is set on the current instance.
- if not, we call `B.objects.get_or_create(a_model=self)` which will either retrieve the existing `B` instance for this `A` instance or create one if none exists yet and we store this `B` instance as `self.__bcache` so next call will retrieve it directly from `__bcache` instead of hitting the database.
- and finally we return `self.__bcache` that is now garanteed to exists and point to the related `B` instance.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider this solution. The only problem I see now: checking property in all the places.

Comment: @yanik what do you mean "checking property in all the places" ? You only need this one property to ensure the associated `B` instance will be created (if necessary) when you access `A().b`.

Comment: @ bruno-desthuilliers don't found any docs about `__bcache` attribute. I want not only use, but understand this method.

Comment: You wont find any doc obviously - you could name it how you want. Python is dynamic, so you can add per-instance or per-class attribute wherever you want. Django models are a bit special but they are still Python classes... NB: I added some explanations to my answer.

Comment: thx for explanations, but i'm not new in Python and Django :) I understand all of these, was just confused about two underscores name, thats it.

Comment: @yanik  ah sorry. The leading double underscore is Python's way to make an attribute as private as it can be - mostly to protect it from accidental name clash actually.